# How do I create a ListView/Listbox with rounded corners in Firemonkey?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.4-sydney

I'm using Firemonkey and I'm trying to style my listview so that it has rounded corners. I was unable to find a way and then tried to do the same with a listbox instead. Listbox provides some custom painting methods I've come across.

Any idea on how to achieve this like on this example:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-do-i-create-a-listview-with-rounded-corners-in-android

Comment: Perhaps use a `TRectangle` (corners can be rounded) as a parent for the `TListView/TListBox`. Set fill colors to be the same.

Comment: I actually also thought of this and tried doing it, but couldn't get the listbox/listview to remove its rectangle drawn.  So now I have two borders...On the Paint event I could set the opacity way up but then the text also is removed

Comment: Try again with `TRectangle` and on top of that a `TListView` with `Transparent = True`. For the rectangle use `Fill.Color` and `Stroke.Color` of your choise.

Comment: I'll report back after I've tried this

Comment: Create a custom listboxstyle (right click the listbox and choose Edit -> Defaults/Custom style). Use a `TRectangle` as tthe background component (replace the existing component with StyleName 'background'. You can set the `XRadius` and `YRadius` properties to the desired radius. Save the style and see the effect in the IDE.